# Issues with making a div and header in a div the same height

Tags: html, css

I have an issue. I want the `div` with the image to have the same height (scaling when you resize the window). Could anyone help me out here? I don't get why the `height: 100%;` doesn't make it's size as big as the parent `div`.

```css
body {
  background-color: darkred;
  color: #bfbfbf;
  font-family: Roboto, serif;
}

.image {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 .5% .5% 0;
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.head:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

header {
  float: right;
  width: 69%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="../assets/Triumph_Spitfire.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <header>
    <h1>Triump Spitfire</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>“poor man’s Jaguar E-type”</p>
  </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flexbox` can be a really good solution here. I removed your floats and set a header size. Setting a height on parent is the easiest way to make children follow that constraint.

```css
body {
  background-color: darkred;
  color: #bfbfbf;
  font-family: Roboto, serif;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 .5% .5% 0;
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.head {
  display: flex;
  height: 135px;
}

div.head:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

header {
  flex: 1;
  height: 135px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image img {
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x250" alt="">
  </div>
  <header>
    <h1>Triump Spitfire</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>“poor man’s Jaguar E-type”</p>
  </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'display: flex, align-items: stretch' to your div with the class 'head'. See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/kqwe4jma/1/

```
.head {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}
```

Comment: this works with small screen but if enlarge it doesnt: try to add an image to the src in css.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. As @Sigma stated, only works for a small screen.

Comment: OK we just needed to remove the height and float styles from the header, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/kqwe4jma/1/

Comment: Strech is the default value for align-items, so you don't need that: https://jsfiddle.net/kqwe4jma/3/